# May I know which one is correct?

Tags: grammar, indirect-speech

between saying

"I told him that if he doesn't hear from me after three days, please call the police."

and

"I told him that if he didn't hear from me after three days, please called the police."

This is confusing since some English speaking people mix present tense and past tense in sentences. Your answer is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence is fine.

My only objection is the use of **called** in the second sentence, because it is an instruction to do something, and has not yet happened.

It also differs by using "didn't hear from me" but that, to me, works because the sentence is projecting into the future, about the past as it would be at that future time.

So the second sentence would be better as

> I told him that if he didn't hear from me after three days, please **call** the police.

Comment: Thank you very much. This makes me understand how to combine tenses in sentences more.

Comment: "I told him that if he doesn't hear from me after three days, please call the police." would get two downmarks from teachers I've met. 'doesn't/didn't hear from me **within** x days' or 'hasn't/hadn't heard from me after x days'. // After a report (told him _that_) rather than a quote structure, 'please call the police' in running text doesn't work.  '... to kindly inform the police.'

Answer (score 0):

The difference is between quotation and explanation.

To report your actual wording you might use the folloiwng.

```
I said to him: "If you don't hear from me for three days, please call the police."
```

If you were reporting the meaning of what you said you might say the following.

```
I told him that if he didn't hear from me for three days, please call the police.
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Is it wrong to say "after three days"?